# Trying to Change Hidden Field Value In Form if a Certain Option is Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have tried researching this and I cannot get it to work. People have asked similar questions but mine is a little different. Basically, we have a form that asks a user for an amount which has an id of `amount_c` in the form. The hidden field in the form is this:

So, if there amount selected is "$7,500 to $9,999" for `amount_c` then the hidden buyer value should be 2, otherwise (if they select any other dollar amount) it should submit the hidden buyer field with a value of 1.

Currently, there is another script that is called to validate the form on submission. It is done so like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/submission.php" method="post" onsubmit="return  validate_form(this); ">
```

Therefore,

1. Should I create another script or add to the existing one?
2. If I can add to the existing one, what have I done wrong below (see below)?
3. If I can create a separate script, how would the form action line change above to call that additional script?

Here is what I have as I added it to the existing script:

```
$(function() {
$('#amount_c').change(function() {
    if (amount_c === "$7,500 to $9,999") {
        var buyer = $("#buyer").val(2);
        } else {
            $("#buyer").val(1);
        }
});
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: amount_c is a variable that you have NOT assigned. It does not automatically equal the value of an element of the same name. You have to set it.

Comment: will this work? 
    `$(function() {
var amount_c = document.getElementById("amount_c"); 
var debtAmount = amount_c.options[amount_c.selectedIndex].value;
var buyer = document.getElementById("buyer");
$('#amount_c').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "$7,500 to $9,999") {
        $("#buyer").val(2);
        } else {
            $("#buyer").val(1);
        }
});
});'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('#amount_c').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "$7,500 to $9,999") {
        $("#buyer").val(2);
        } else {
            $("#buyer").val(1);
        }
});
});
```